# List records into pdf format c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, list, pdf, itext

I got myself a task to pull out a set of records from database and make it to pdf file.

```
List<EligibilityCheckReportInfo> list = dbManager.GetEligibiltyCheckReportInfo(" where ( eligibility_check.REGDATE BETWEEN '" + dbManager.GetMySqlType("01/02/2017") + "' AND '" + dbManager.GetMySqlType2("14/02/2017") + "' ) ");
```

the "list" is the data I generated from database. I need to convert the list into pdf. Can anyone show me the way of doing this? Any guidance or tips will be much appreciated. I have tried to look for answer from google, but I can only found the article which convert from gridview to pdf. Thanks in advance, guys.

Comment: .NET framework has not native PDF support. There are several commercial or open-source libraries that you could use, i.e. [iTextSharp](https://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/)

Comment: Yeap, I used itextsharp to convert the gridview into pdf before. But I do not know the way of using itextsharp to convert the list into pdf.

Comment: I am not an expert of that library, but its website says: `Several iText engineers are actively supporting the project on on StackOverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/itext` You could use this tag to target your question better

Comment: @SimoneCifani Yes, we actively spend time on stackoverflow as part of our job. We strongly believe part of what makes iText great is the support and the community feeling.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few options, depending on your specific usecase.

We currently do not have a direct conversion from your desired datatype to pdf.
So, it will come down to you doing some of the work yourself.
Not a lot however.

Have a look at our website (in particular the samples) to check how you'd go about making a table with iText. There's no need of calculating coordinates. All you do is define how many columns you'd like your table to have, and then add cells to your table.

http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples-itext7

```
protected void manipulatePdf(String dest) throws Exception {
    PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(dest));
    Document doc = new Document(pdfDoc);

    Table table = new Table(8);
    for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
        table.addCell("hi");
    }
    doc.add(table);

    doc.close();
}
```

So, like I said, the amount of work needed for your usecase depends how thoroughly/generically you want to solve this problem.
You can implement something that works perfectly for just your data. Or you could go about making a generic version that handles arbitrary gridview.

Ultimately though, what iText expects is that you give it some textual value for each cell.

Comment: Hi, sir, thanks for the help. I would like to ask what are the content is in the 'dest' on the code above.

Comment: This is an example from the itext website. It writes the pdf document to a file. The variable "dest" is the path to which the file is written.

Answer (score 2):

Easy way - ArrayToPdf ([github](https://github.com/mustaddon/ArrayToPdf), 
[nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ArrayToPdf))

```
byte[] pdf = myList.ToPdf();
File.WriteAllBytes("result.pdf", pdf);
```